# No entiendo el operador lógico NOT (!) en C

Tags: c

No entiendo el operador lógico NOT en **[c](/questions/tagged/c)**, ¿alguien podría ayudarme con algunos ejemplos fáciles y algún que otro difícil para pensar?.

No entiendo por qué existe, dice que si es `true`, pasa a `false`, pero si es `false`, pasa a `true`.

Pero, ¿para qué?, si yo tengo una información que es verdadera, ¿para qué voy a querer pasarla como falsa?

Por ejemplo, en este código:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){

    int n = 10, b = 5;

    if(!(n > b)){
        printf("n no es mayor a b.\n");
    }else{
        printf("n es mayor a b.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Básicamente, uso el `!` para que el resultado positivo vaya al `else`, ¿es por eso que usamos el operador NOT?.

Comment: No es un capricho del lenguaje. La mayoría posee el operador de negación lógica. Es un regalo del álgebra booleana. Por ejemplo, si tienes una puerta y solo sabes si está abierta, porque sí . ¿Está abierta? Solo tienes dos respuestas. Si o no. Supongamos que quieres saber si está cerrada. Bueno, si la puerta está abierta significa que no está cerrada y si no está abierta significa que no está cerrada.

Comment: En lógica existe una dualidad. La negación te permite expresar un valor respecto a otro. Todo es relativo. Si aún tienes dudas, pregúntale a Boole por qué creó el operador de negación.

Comment: Jejeje, ahorita estas empezando y te parece inútil el operador not, pero en el futuro te sera unos de los operadores más útiles :D.

Comment: @Cris223511.dev seguro? while (!finished) te parece inutil?

Comment: Te dieron unas lindas explicaciones, pero por favor, lee ALGEBRA DE BOOL... eso es lo que tenes que saber, para entender porque esto es tan importante como el and o el or...

Comment: Si no entiendes : `if(!entiendes)`. Tú mismo aplicas la negación en tu pregunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El operador "negación" es un operador de área de la [lógica proposicional](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B3gica_proposicional) y existe en todos los lenguajes que he llegado a conocer, incluso me atrevería a señalar que seguramente existe en absolutamente todos los lenguajes.

Porque la programación tiene mucho que ver con la lógica proposicional, de hecho recuerdo mi primer curso de programación empezaba con ese tópico. Esto es porque tiene una relación con matemáticas binarias, ya que el `True` lo podemos pensar como un `1` y el `False` como `0` (y comprenderás lo importante que es el sistema binario en la computación!). Incluso tiene un equivalente en electrónica, como por ejemplo el chip `74LS04` el cual es básicamente 6 compuertas `NOT` (es decir negación).

Entonces, podríamos decir que está en las raíces de la programación.

Dicho todo esto, creo entender tu pregunta. Porque en la práctica ¿de que le sirve al desarrollador final este operador?

Se usa mucho cuando trabajas con binarios, sobre todo en protocolos de comunicación o lecturas de archivo que están en binario. Estos temas no son del todo raros, pero no es lo habitual. En el día a día (y según mi experiencia), quizás para lo que más se usa es para invertir el orden del `if`

Es decir, tenemos el tipico `if/else` al usar la negación en el `if`, invertimos la situación y lo que antes se ejecutaba en el `if` ahora lo ejecutamos en el `else` y viceversa.

**¿Pero para que? !!**

Simplemente por legibilidad del código, digamos que tienes algo así

```
int GetValor(){
   if(Expresion){
      //Aquí muchas lineas de código
      return 1;
   }
   else{
     return 0;
   }
}
```

Este es un caso muy típico, donde tenemos un `if` que dentro tiene mucho código y puede tener dentro más niveles de anidación. Y el `else` es corto y simple. Este código es fácil de mejorar usando la negación

```
int GetValor(){
   if( !Expresion ) return 0;
   
   //Aquí muchas líneas de código
}
```

Como verás hemos eliminado un nivel de anidación.

Otro uso, quizás no tan habitual es cuando tienes un estado binario, aquí se usa para invertir el estado

```
isActivo = !isActivo
//isActivo es del tipo bool
```

Answer (score 5):

Imagina que está lloviendo ¿Qué sería lo apropiado?

- Si estoy fuera de casa y uso un paraguas -> apropiado
- Si estoy fuera de casa y no uso paraguas -> inapropiado, me mojo
- Si estoy dentro de casa y uso un paraguas -> inapropiado, innecesario
- Si estoy dentro de casa y no uso un paraguas -> apropiado

Esto se puede modelizar así:

```
apropiado = (dentroCasa && !usoParaguas) || (!dentroDeCasa && usoParaguas)
```

En esta situación que es más compleja que el caso que expones, no te puedes escapar de usar el operador de negación (!), por lo que es un operador necesario.

Nota: La condición anterior se podría definir como un XOR haciendo innecesario el NOT, pero lo mantengo para exponer la necesidad del operador NOT.

Answer (score 5):

es bastante simple

el operado `!` es una negacion es decir lo contrario de lo que seria:

definimos un string animal con `si` lo que vendria a ser `true` o `verdad`

```
char animal[] = true;
```

ahora si le agregamo el operador `!` serio lo contrario `false` o `falso`
negamos que sea animal

```
!animal
```

esto tambien funciona a lo contrario de `false -> true` y de `true -> false`

ahora tu codigo

```
int n = 10, b = 5;
if( !(n > b) )
```

en programacion solo se entiende una expresion como `true` o `false` es `verdad` o no lo `es`

**evaluemos la primeros parentesis  `(n > b)` n es mayor que b?**

la respuesta obvia es que `si` osea `true`

pero al negarlo se vuelve `no` osea `false` y biceversa

si es `false` al negarlo pasaria a ser `true`

Answer (score 4):

Te pongo un ejemplo practico muy sencillo:
Para simular un botón, y que el botón tenga dos posiciones, encendido y apagado,como el botón solo tiene dos posiciones, puede ser una variable booleana, 0=apagado y 1=encendido.
Una manera simple de invertir el estado del botón cada vez que lo pulsas, simplemente es negar su estado `boton=!boton;`, de esta manera si está encendido pasa a apagado, y si está apagado pasa a encendido.
Te pongo un ejemplo en JS para que veas aquí el resultado (antes de votar negativo tened en cuenta que tiene problemas de concepto, no lenguaje, no seáis talibanes)

```js
function pulsar(){
  var pulsado=boton.style.backgroundColor=="yellow";
  pulsado=!pulsado;
  if (pulsado) boton.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
  else boton.style.backgroundColor="inherit";
}
```

```html
<button id=boton onclick=pulsar()>Púlsame</button>
```

Comment: La pregunta es sobre C, por más que sea inherente a cualquier lenguaje de programación.

Comment: La pregunta es sobre un concepto básico de álgebra de boole y este sitio solo acepta ejemplos funcionales en javascript. No usar esa herramienta para mostrar ejemplos es contradictorio.

Comment: Debo admitir que el ejemplo está muy bien. Más allá de que haya sido bien recibido, espero que el OP también lo encuentre útil.

Answer (score 3):

Sales de casa, miras al cielo y se ve con nube no se ve sol. Tu pensarías: Si no está soleado y hay viento, entonces lloverá. Piensas si va a llover yo no salgo. Esto se puede codificar en código c:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define BOOL unsigned char
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#define TIEMPO_ACTUAL FALSE
#define CLIMA_ACTUAL TRUE
int main(void){
    BOOL soleado=TIEMPO_ACTUAL,hay_viento=CLIMA_ACTUAL;
    BOOL va_a_llover=(!soleado && hay_viento);
    BOOL saldre=!va_a_llover;
    printf("%s entonces %s a salir\n",
        (va_a_llover)?"Esta nublado y hay mucho viento":"Esta soleado",
        (saldre)?"voy":"no voy"
    );
     printf("(!soleado && hay_viento) es lo mismo que (!%d && %d) y da como resultado: %d\n",soleado,hay_viento,va_a_llover);
    return !1;//Lo mismo que poner 0
}
```

Como resultado da:

> Esta nublado y hay mucho viento entonces no voy a salir
> !soleado && hay_viento) es lo mismo que (!0 && 1) y da como resultado: 1

El operador `!` sirve para negar. En otras palabras, todo lo que no sea 0 lo convierte en 0, si es 0 lo convierte en 1. En c si no es 0 es verdadero y cumpre el if, si es 0 es falso no cumple el if.

Referente al operador not `!` en este código tenemos al and. Que es como una comparación: `TRUE && TRUE` da 1. `FALSE && FALSE` da 0. `TRUE && FALSE` y `FALSE && TRUE` dan 0. Lo que significa que los dos debe ser verdadero para que de 1 o `TRUE`. Como un ejemplo diría:

> Voy a buscar agua si está abierto y tengo rial para comprarla.